# Can Robocopy Copy Only ADS (Alternate Data Streams) ? i.e. Not Re-Copy the Data/Security

Tags: backup, ads, ntfs, robocopy, alternate-data-stream

I'm not sure I really understand ADS, but it seems that a file has a main one then potentially more.  Well, I ran a program and discovered that my source drive has about 700 ADS more than what the destination drive has after performing a robocopy.

I know that robocopy can copy ADS, since I started with a blank drive, then scanned with an ADS scanner revealing the ADSes of robocopied files.

So, can someone help clear up the confusion?  Can I use robocopy to copy only an ADS? How do I get the number of ADS on each volume to match exactly?

Comment: I've done a little more reading about ADS, and it seems that a folder can have an ADS.  Since the robocopy command I used was simply "/copyall" and "/dcopy:T", I believe that the ADS from the folders were never copied.  Only the files.  It looks like I have to copy ADS from folders and hopefully this fixes the missing 700 of them.

Comment: Found KB article KB2646535; it adds /dcopy:A and D commands to robocopy.  I'm hoping this resolves the ADS issue.